# Rewrite Base in Joomla Issues

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla

I recently changed servers and moved the site. Earlier the site was in the root of the server. Now its under public_html/joomla.com folder.

The problem is all my links are not working.They are throwing up a 404 page not found error.

my htaccess reads something like below

```
`#  mod_rewrite in use
########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
#php_value post_max_size 5M
#php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
`
```

I doubt the reqritebase issue - is this the issue or how can I get back all the links to work?

Please help soon.

Thanks

Comment: did you change your live_site variable in your configuration.php ? Looks to me that you moved your site to a new domain name?

Comment: I did move it to a new host provider with same domain name. So I did not find the need to change the live site url. It still says this var $live_site = 'http://thepanamainsider.com'; in the configuration file.

Comment: can you move the joomla folders and files from public_html/joomla.com to public_html ? Also check if the panamainsider.com in your hosting cpanel is directing to the public_html folder and joomla.com (public_html is the root of your server)

Comment: I dont wish to do this . I want joomla to be in the folder : panamainsider.com. Can you suggest some changes needed to be done in order for the links to work as per the current structure of my site?

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line :

```
# RewriteBase /
```

with :

```
RewriteBase /joomla.com
```